# Laptop cannot maintain wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, wireless-router

I have an HP Pavilion laptop and I am having issues with getting the laptop to stay connected to the wireless network.

I looked at the power management in the WLAN card for the laptop and that is un-checked. I also took at the devices that could be connected to the network and it's just my two laptops.

My router has dual band wireless connection and my other laptop (Asus) manages fine in terms of remaining connected to the wireless network. Not only does this laptop have any issues with wireless connection but it also connects to the 5G network while my HP struggles to connect with the 2G network.

The connection drops literally every 5 minutes and I have to disconnect and then re-connect and hope that the connection remains stable.

What recommendations are there for solving this issue?

Comment: Well, first of all, 2.4Ghz is far more prone to interference. The band is completely swamped in any dense area and can be almost useless even if you stand right next to your access point. The other thing could be hardware or driver related. Do yourself a favor and buy a $15 USB nano 5Ghz wireless N network adapter and your problems will be solved. That's what I did, because at my new home my once perfect laptop became useless with all the neighbors.

Comment: What type of wireless router are you using, and secondly where is the laptop located in relation to the router? for line of sight, is it clear or lots of walls and appliances? and Third.. what troubleshooting have you already done?